# How can I make a derived constructor pass a concatenated value to its parent constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I have two exception classes, with one inheriting from the other:

```
class bmd2Exception : public std::runtime_error
{
  public:
    bmd2Exception(const std::string & _description) throw () : std::runtime_error(_description) {}
    ~bmd2Exception() throw() {}
};

class bmd2FileException : public bmd2Exception
{
  public:
    bmd2FileException(const std::string & _description, const char * _file, long int _line) throw()
    {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << "ERROR in " << _file << " at line " << _line << ": " << _description;
      bmd2Exception(ss.str());
    }
    ~bmd2FileException() throw() {}
};
```

The error message I get:

```
no matching function for call to ‘bmd2::bmd2Exception::bmd2Exception()’
```

I understand this is because the constructor for bmd2FileException is trying to call bmd2Exception(), which has not been defined.  What I really want to happen is for bmd2FileException() to call bmd2Exception(const std::string &) with the concatenated error message.  How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the mem-initializer-list: `bmd2FileException(/*parameters*/) : bmd2Exception(/*concatenated string*/) {}` or use another class design (e.g. a protected default ctor in `bmd2Exception` and provide some kind of setter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common paradigm is to create a helper function:

```
class bmd2FileException : public bmd2Exception
{
    private:
        static std::string make_msg(const std::string & _description, const char * _file, long int _line);

    public:
        bmd2FileException(const std::string & _description, const char * _file, long int _line)
            : bmd2Exception(make_msg(_description, _file, _line))
        { }      
};
```

Now just put your message-creating code in `bmd2FileException::make_msg(...)`.

By the way, if your constructor is concatenating strings, I wouldn't be so sure it is `throw()`.

Comment: +1. Also correct about the unnecessary `throw`. Streams don't throw any exceptions unless explicitly enabled via its [exceptions mask](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/). If `std::bad_alloc` is thrown, you got bigger problems as the destructor will never be called.

Comment: We just use the `throw` to be explicit that this function shouldn't, under reasonable circumstance, throw anything.